# Authentification Symfony Production "Invalid Credentials"

Tags: symfony, authentication, production-environment

I finally and not without difficulty managed to put my site on line on heroku! :) It works and I have implemented data in my base. Here is the link to the site: https://societe-espion.herokuapp.com/mission/
But the login/ page when I try to connect with my credentials gives me the error: "Invalid credentials"
I cannot find my mistake after several searches.
I also send you my git repository with my files. https://github.com/marinebde/societe-espion.git
Could you help me?
thank you

Comment: How have you set your password in your database ? The password was properly encoded thanks to bcrypt as you configured your security.yaml ?

Comment: try to manually re-hash a password with `php bin/console security:hash-password` And put it in the db. Or try to create a new user with the wizard : `php bin/console make:user`.  And you should remove the credentials from your git repository, especially if your site is in production